# Retrieval issue while writing integration test cases

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, integration-testing, querydsl, in-memory-database

We are facing issue while writing integration test cases for code.

We are having two entities on our application "EntityGroup" and "Entity". Having one to many relationship that means one EntityGroup can have multiple "Entity". Below is the defination of EntityGroup and Entity

```
public class EntityGroup extends BaseDomain {

    @Column(name = "entitygroup_name")
    private String entityGroupName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<EntityGroupConfig> entityGroupConfigs = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "entitygroup", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entitygroup_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Entity> entities= new ArrayList<>();
   
}

public class Entity extends BaseDomain {

    @Column(name = "entity_name")
    private String entityName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<EntityConfig> entityConfigs = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Service Layer Call:

```
final EntityGroup entityGroup = entityGroupDAO.getEntityGroupByEntityName(entityName);
```

Option A: Dao Layer Implementation on actual environment.

```
public EntityGroup getEntityGroupByEntityName(String entityName) {
        final JPQLQuery<EntityGroup> jpqlQuery = (JPQLQuery<EntityGroup>) jpaQueryFactory
                .from(entityGroup)
                .leftJoin(entityGroup.entityGroupConfigs, entityGroupConfig).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(entityGroup.entity, entity).fetchAll()
                .leftJoin(entity.entityConfigs, entityConfig).fetchAll()
                .where(entity.entityName.eq(entityName))
                .orderBy(entityGroupConfig.entityLogDate.desc())
                .select(entityGroup).distinct();

        return jpqlQuery.fetchOne();
```

Option B: Dao Layer workaround for integration test cases.

```
public EntityGroup getEntityGroupByEntityName(String entityName) {
        final List<Entity> entities = jpaQueryFactory
                .from(entity)
                .select(entity).distinct()
                .leftJoin(entity.entityConfigs, entityConfig).fetchJoin()
                .where(entity.entityName.eq(entityName))
                .fetch();

        final Map<UUID, Entity> entityById = entities.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getId, Function.identity()));

        final EntityGroup entityGroupResponse = jpaQueryFactory
                .from(entityGroup)
                .select(entityGroup).distinct()
                .leftJoin(entityGroup.entityGroupConfigs, entityGroupConfig).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(entityGroup.entities, entity)
                .where(entity.in(entityById.values()))
                .orderBy(entityGroupConfig.entityLogDate.desc())
                .fetchOne();

        final List<Entity> entityGroupModels = entityGroupResponse.getEntities().stream().map(entity -> {
            return entitiesById.get(entity.getId());
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(entityGroupEntities)) entityGroupResponse.setEntities(entitiyGroupEntities);
        return entityGroupResponse;
    }
```

**Problem:** From the service layer when we are calling entityGroupDAO.getEntityGroupByEntityName(entityName) in actual environment where our database is MSSQL, this is working perfectly fine (Option A). But when we are writing integration test cases in which our database is In-Memory(H2) databse then Option A approach is returing entityName as null. So we did the workaround implementaion of Dao layer (Option B) just for integration test cases.

Can anyone please help why Option A is not working in integration test cases.

**Technical Stack: Amazon Correto 11, Spring boot, QueryDSL, In-Memory Database (H2)**

Regards
Aditya